# How to fix Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) error in Next 13?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

Ive installed a package called `lqip-modern` in my Next 13.4 project. I wanted to use this package to create a blur placeholder for my Image. Now after i install this package my app is no longer working and throwing a webpack error. the error it displaying is

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

what is the fix for this error?